# Find the width of a view inside of a fragment

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin

I want to find the width of a view inside of a fragment and I've written the following code

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {

var team1_value = 0


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v =  inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_queens, container, false)

    val width = v.layout_team1_picker.width.toFloat()

    Log.d("width1","width is $width")


    return v
}
```

The answer I get is 0.0. Howerver if I do the same thing inside of a button

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {

var team1_value = 0


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v =  inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_queens, container, false)

        v.image_team1_plus.setOnClickListener{

        val width = v.layout_team1_picker.width.toFloat()

        Log.d("width2","width is $width")
    }
    return v
}
```

I get a positive 320.0 whenever I press the button. Why is this the case?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Answer (score 0):

Because in the onClick case, you're running the code when the button is clicked, which is after the view has been packed / rendered. In the onCreateView case, you're running the code when it is created, which is before it is packed / rendered, so it doesn't yet have a size.

If you moved the width-displaying code from `onCreateView` to `onStart`, which is called when the fragment is visible, then you should see the desired behaviour.

Comment: I tried to do this but I still get 0. This is the code   override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val width = v!!.layout_team1_picker.width.toFloat()

        Log.d("picker","widht is $width")
    }

Comment: Is the view being created and the image (I'm guessing `v.image_team1_plus` is an image) dynamically added afterwards? Or anything else happening that might cause a 0-sized view to have a size later? It is possible to change the size of a view late in its lifecycle (after onStart), but onStart _should_ be good enough...

Comment: No nothing is being added dynamically. Everything is defined in fragment_example.xml

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onViewCreated` method and get the width inside.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, during onCreateView, your views still have no size yet. Another approach would be to add a GlobalLayoutListener, to be aware of when your view has been rendered.

There are different ways of achieving this, here's a nice breakdown of it :
https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-ongloballayoutlistener/

Basically :

Create an extension function to
 1. wait for the view to be rendered (by attaching a globalLayoutListener to its viewTreeObserver)
 2. Call whatever function you want once width/height are known

```
inline fun <T: View> T.afterMeasured(crossinline f: T.() -> Unit) {

    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

        override fun onGlobalLayout() {

            if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {

                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                f()

            }

        }

    })

}
```

To call it, simply do :

```
v.layout_team1_picker.afterMeasured {

  Log.d("width1","width is $v.layout_team1_picker.width")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get width after all views were rendered, so use view.post

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // ...

    view.post {
      val width = v.layout_team1_picker.width.toFloat()
    }
  }
```